# Capture Ratio Calculation (KeyError: 'Date'), Python

Tags: python, pandas, keyerror

I am trying to create a python function which would allow me to pass on SP500 tickers and calculate their upside capture ratio over time. However, I get thos keyError 'Date' and Cannot figure out why, I even tried to write the whole function from the beginning, step by step. When I run the funtion with couple tickers, it runs just fine. Yet it starts to give me the error once I try to run with many tickers. I am new here, and new to programming. I appreciate your help and time!

```
table = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')
tickers = table[0]['Symbol'].values

start_date= '2020-12-31'
end_date = dt.datetime.now()
benchmark = 'SPY'


def upside_capture_ratio(tickers,start='start date', end='end_date',benchmark='SPY'):
    """
    Takes a list of tickers and returns the upside capture ratio overtime


"""
upside_results=[]

for ticker in tickers:

    #Pulling benchmark data from yahoo finance as well as positive returns and corresponding periods
    benchmark_daily_prices= pdr.DataReader(benchmark, 'yahoo', start_date, end_date)
    benchmark_daily_returns = benchmark_daily_prices.pct_change().dropna()
    up_benchmark_periods = benchmark_daily_returns[benchmark_daily_returns['Adj Close']>0].reset_index()['Date']
    positive_benchmark_returns = benchmark_daily_returns.loc[up_benchmark_periods][['Adj Close']].rename(columns={'Adj Close':'Returns'})

    #Pulling ticker information from yahoo finance as well as positive returns and corresponding positive benchmark periods

    ticker_prices_daily = pdr.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start_date, end_date)
    ticker_daily_returns = ticker_prices_daily.pct_change().dropna()
    ticker_returns_when_benchmark_up = ticker_daily_returns.loc[up_benchmark_periods][['Adj Close']].rename(columns={'Adj Close':'Returns'})

    compounded_benchmark_positive_returns = (positive_benchmark_returns+1).cumprod()
    compounded_ticker_positive_returns = (ticker_returns_when_benchmark_up+1).cumprod()

    upside_capture_ratio = (compounded_ticker_positive_returns)/(compounded_benchmark_positive_returns)
    upside_capture_ratio.rename(columns={'Returns':f'Upside_Capture_Overtime for {ticker}'}, inplace=True)

    upside_results.append(upside_capture_ratio)
    
return pd.concat(upside_results, axis=1)`


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3079             try:
-> 3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3081             except KeyError as err:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Date'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-251dcb7c65dd> in <module>
----> 1 upside_capture_ratio(tickers=tickers,start=start_date, end=end_date, benchmark='SPY')

<ipython-input-35-b9f22bff5751> in upside_capture_ratio(tickers, start, end, benchmark)
     24         #Pulling ticker information from yahoo finance as well as positive returns and corresponding positive benchmark periods
     25 
---> 26         ticker_prices_daily = pdr.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start_date, end_date)
     27         ticker_daily_returns = ticker_prices_daily.pct_change().dropna()
     28         ticker_returns_when_benchmark_up = ticker_daily_returns.loc[up_benchmark_periods][['Adj Close']].rename(columns={'Adj Close':'Returns'})

    > ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in
    > wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    >     197                 else:
    >     198                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
    > --> 199             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    >     200 
    >     201         return cast(F, wrapper)
    > 
    > ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py in
    > DataReader(name, data_source, start, end, retry_count, pause, session,
    > api_key)
    >     368 
    >     369     if data_source == "yahoo":
    > --> 370         return YahooDailyReader(
    >     371             symbols=name,
    >     372             start=start,
    > 
    > ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py in read(self)
    >     251         # If a single symbol, (e.g., 'GOOG')
    >     252         if isinstance(self.symbols, (string_types, int)):
    > --> 253             df = self._read_one_data(self.url, params=self._get_params(self.symbols))
    >     254         # Or multiple symbols, (e.g., ['GOOG', 'AAPL', 'MSFT'])
    >     255         elif isinstance(self.symbols, DataFrame):
    > 
    > ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\yahoo\daily.py in
    > _read_one_data(self, url, params)
    >     159         prices = DataFrame(data["prices"])
    >     160         prices.columns = [col.capitalize() for col in prices.columns]
    > --> 161         prices["Date"] = to_datetime(to_datetime(prices["Date"], unit="s").dt.date)
    >     162 
    >     163         if "Data" in prices.columns:
    > 
    > ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in
    > __getitem__(self, key)    3022             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:    3023                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
    > -> 3024             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)    3025             if is_integer(indexer):    3026                 indexer = [indexer]
    > 
    > ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in
    > get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    3080                 return
    > self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)    3081             except KeyError
    > as err:
    > -> 3082                 raise KeyError(key) from err    3083     3084         if tolerance is not None:
    > 
    > KeyError: 'Date'
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs on the ticker BRK.B. If you look at finance.yahoo, the ticker is BF-B. I tried to check in a loop whether there are still such tickers with a dot. There were two in total: BRK.B, BF.B.
[BF-B](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BF-B/)
[BRK-B](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BRK-B/)

```
for ticker in tickers:
    if ticker.find(".")!=-1:
        print(ticker)
```

Converted these tickers by replacing the dot with a dash.

```
tickers = np.array([i.replace('.', '-') for i in tickers])
```

Comment: You can mark the answer by checking the box below the top and bottom triangles.